# Ask before disconnecting logged-in user on RDP / Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I am not able to find this information or to Google it so here it is:

Me and a friend share 1 account on Windows Server 2012 (R2 Datacenter) virtual server. We use this to host one application and there is no need to use it few times per day at maximum so one shared account is fine with us. We connect using RDP.

It happens that when he is logged in and I try to log-in, it forces him to log off. Now, I remember, that in past I used a RDP connection on older version of Windows Server (configured by someone else) and it always asked, whether I wanted to continue with logging and disconnect currently logged user or stop the action.

Is that possible on my server - that is ask before disconnecting currently logged user?

Thanks :-)

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

No, because it is the same account. If it was a second account, it should prompt you to disconnect the currently logged on user.